# what should i do next for creating my game bot in telegram?

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot

I have made a bot in telegram.

next used the /newgame command to make new game.

the botfather made it and now I get this message:

"You can now use Example as the short_name parameter value in Bot API. Your game link is t.me/NanoNewsBot?game=Example. Open it to start developing the game!"

what should I do next?
I clicked on it and it opens the forward window. I forward it to my bot and nothing happens.

Comment: Did you solved the issue?

Answer (score -1):

I answered this question in this question:
[Telegram Bot Game not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42188779/telegram-bot-game-not-working/42190835#42190835)

An example in PHP:

```
if(isset($update["callback_query"])) {
    $parameters["method"] = "answerCallbackQuery";
    $parameters["callback_query_id"] = $update["callback_query"]["id"];
    $parameters["url"] = "<url-game>";
    echo json_encode($parameters);  
    die;
}
```